# How can I drive my serenity framework to run test on Browserstack as well as local machine (while developing scripts) via environment variable

Tags: browserstack, serenity-bdd

I'm using Serenity BDD framework and my need is to run Smoke suite on Browserstack and also run test on local machine while developing the scripts.

I'm able to run tests on both the places separately by changing in serenity.conf file. But I want to setup Environment variables so that I can run tests on any place (Browserstack or local machine) based on needs.

My serenity.conf file is:

```
/*Local machine run 
webdriver {
driver = chrome
autodownload = true
 } */

/*Browserstack Run
webdriver {
    driver = remote
    remote.url = "http://<username>:<acceskey>@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"
}
*/
headless.mode = true

chrome.switches="""--start-maximized;--no-sandbox;--disable-dev-shm-usage;--allow-running-insecure-content;--verbose;,--ignore-certificate-errors;
    --disable-popup-blocking;--disable-default-apps;--disable-extensions-file-access-check;--incognito;--disable-infobars"""

environments {
  default {
    test.base.url = "https://google.com"
  }
  qa {
     test.base.url = "https://google-test.com"
  }
  staging {
     test.base.url = "https://google-test2.com"
  }
  prod {
     test.base.url = "https://google-test3.com"
  }
  all{
  test.page="#{test.base.url}"
  }
}
browserstack {
    user = "<userName>"
    key = "<accesskey>"
    server = hub-cloud.browserstack.com
    browser = chrome
#   device = "iPhone 12"
 #  osVersion = "14"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did read your use case and would like to let you know that you would not be able to run tests on both local and Browserstack at the same time and would require you to run individually only.

On the configuration part, you can try the same, and should it work then great else it is not a supported functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't need to run test on both local and Browserstack at the same. My need is to run test in local or browserstack on need basis and it should be driven from environment configuration. Please suggest on the same

Comment: This is something that you are required to look into at your end on the configurations part as we can suggest and help you debug the issue only if it is related to a Browserstack product.
Also, you can try researching online resources for such scenarios if possible.